# What are the correct permissions to manage youtube captions

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

Am building a software which should manage user's videos captions, the current permissions I use are

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner",
```

but the consent screen shows this warning message

[image]

`permanently delete your YouTube videos`, how do I exclude such permission ?

as per youtube [yotube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/update), those are required

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#youtube) for each of the scopes you are using.

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload`  Manage your YouTube videos
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`   See, edit, and permanently delete your YouTube videos, ratings, comments and captions
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner`  View and manage your assets and associated content on YouTube

You will see that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl` gives you access to delete.  So if you want to remove the access to delete you will need to remove the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl` scope.

You cant pick and choose what a scope grants you access to that is defined by the owner of the authorization server in this case YouTube or google.

Scopes with google normally come in read-only and read-write.  So if you want to update something your also going to have access to delete it.

Comment: true, but that's needed for the captions only, not the whole video, is there a way to do that ? users will be concerned to use the service if they saw that I can delete their whole work which doesn't make lot of sense

Comment: Its an all or nothing "videos, ratings, comments and captions"  This is an old api it doesnt have the granularity that we would like it to have.